# Change product url when changing product name

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, catalog, url-rewrite

Are there any extensions or settings that can change the product url when you change the product name.

Before example:

- Product name: Product 1
- Product url: product-1

After example:

- Product name: Product 12
- Product url: product-12

I want this to be like the example above.

Comment: there is an extension which allows you to use variables when mass changing attributes, but I can't remember the name, so you can say {oldname}2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to import a CSV with columns `store, sku, name, url_key` and update the listings that way. Then reindex your site and you'll see the changes

Answer (score 0):

Modify `url key` attribute to your desired value under catalog -> Manage products -> general tab

Comment: That's not exactly what i mean. I mean to change all changed products to a new url.

Comment: Either you can import all the products with sku and url-key and then re-import same with modified url keys or create a script that will iterate through all the products and modify url key.

Comment: But there is no extension for this yet?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess there is no such extension.

Comment: My website, recently update products name, how can i update my url key also. Now the product name and url key look like diff.